Could a pond poisoned with chloride cause mutated mosquitoes
We've got an old, small concrete pond in our garden. There's no fish or plants in it, only green algae. Every summer, countless mosquito larvae teem in the water.
Normally we take out the water, but this time my wife just threw a bottle of chlorine into the water (toilet cleaner).
I'm concerned about the impact of this to the mosquitoes. I know chlorine is carcinogenic and thus can cause mutations in cells.
To my surprise, after a few days the mosquito lervae are still alive and their activity and number seems to be the same.
My question is: Can the polluted water damage the DNA and cause a hereditary change in the mosquitoes' family tree?
And are mosquitoes adapted so well to polluted water?

Use laborious fish (fish that eat mosquito larvae) they are far more ecologically friendly and has been used in mosquito control for many decades. A bottle of chlorine will wipe out everything, i.e. no mosquito larvae, microbiome, zero ecosystem - unless you've a massive pond that will sufficiently dilute the chlorine.  Laborious fish are tried and tested method globally.

There are a host of other "green" methods to stop the mosquito larvae, it's an area of sustained research since well before my time right up to the present. "Bottle of chlorine" was never amongst those methods. Based on mosquito resistance  studies to insecticides low concentration chlorine over a sustained period, could possibly produce "low concentration chlorine resistance" but it would have to be really low concentration, e.g. does this happen with chlorinated outdoor swimming pools(?? I don't think so).

@M__ comments are not for answers. If you believe your comments answer the question, please include them in an answer with proper citations supporting your claims.
